# KVO binding causes program to freeze?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, scrollview, key-value-observing

I have sort of an odd question concerning a process which appears to get stuck in a wait status at what appears to be random intervals and am hoping I can get some help concerning this.

When the user starts the application, a window is displayed which collects various data and pick list file entries from the user.  The user then presses a 'run' button and the app delegate method related to the 'run' button instantiates a class (TestBindingClass) which has a method in it which will eventually be run in the background.  It then fires up a second xib file which displays a second window which contains an empty scroll view.  As part of initiating the second window in the windowDIdLoad method, the second window code registers as an observer of a property of TestBindingClass.  Finally, the main window 'run' method has executes the second thread method inside of TestBindingClass which adds entries into a NSMutableArray and also triggers the monitored property each time a new entry is added.  Each entry into the NSMutableArray is a line of text (a string) which is to be displayed into the second xib scroll view.

TestBindingClass is the (relatively) empty shell of a class which will have extensive calculations in it which will emit status messages as certain checkpoints are reached.  Those check point messages will be displayed in the scroll view.

Mostly, this works fine.  In fact, sometimes this works perfectly.  Other times the process seems to freeze up and only displays a few of the status lines before hanging up in a wait loop.  Usually this is a the point where the scroll view is about to expand past the window size and the scroll bar would become activated.  The odd thing is that if I add debugging breakpoints into the add observer method in the second xib code, it ALWAYS works properly.

So much for the description... let's show some code....

Here is the code for the 'run' button method in the main window

```
-(IBAction)runButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
 // do a bunch of stuff

 TestBindingClass* tempTestBindingClass = [[TestBindingClass alloc] init];

 RunResultWindowController = [[RunResultWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"RunResultWindow"];
RunResultWindowController.localTestBindingClass=tempTestBindingClass;
[RunResultWindowController showWindow:self];

[self.StatusDisplayOutput setStringValue:@"Run Complete"];

[tempTestBindingClass submitStatusStringSequence];

}
```

Here is the code for the TestBindingClass as referenced above.  StatusStrings is the Mutable array which will contain the list of status strings which should be eventually displayed in the scroll view which is observing this class via the arraystatuscounter property.

```
 //  TestBindingClass.h

 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface TestBindingClass : NSObject {

NSMutableArray *StatusStrings;
   int arraystatuscounter;


 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *StatusStrings;
 @property  int arraystatuscounter;

 - (void) runStatusStringSequence:(id)param;
 - (void) submitStatusStringSequence;

 @end
```

This shows the code of TestBindingClass which is pretty simple.  Just drop goofy little strings into the NSMutableArray one at a time and dinks the arraystatuscounter property each time it adds a string into the array.

```
 //  TestBindingClass.m

 - (void) submitStatusStringSequence
 {

     [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(runStatusStringSequence:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

 }


 - (void) runStatusStringSequence:(id)param 
 {


NSMutableArray *StatusStringsAlloc = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
StatusStrings = StatusStringsAlloc;

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"first string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:1];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"second string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:2];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"third string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:3];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"fourth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:4];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"fifth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:5];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"sixth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:6];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"seventh string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:7];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"last string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:8];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"first string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:1];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"second string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:2];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"third string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:3];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"fourth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:4];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"fifth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:5];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"sixth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:6];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"seventh string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:7];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"last string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:8];

 }
```

Here is the RunResultWindows window controller code. The address for the TestBindingClass is added into the ivars so that it can properly set up the necessary KVO observer settings.

```
 //  RunResultWindow.h

 @interface RunResultWindow : NSWindowController {

  NSTextView *RunResultWindowTextView;
  TestBindingClass *localTestBindingClass;
 }

 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;

 @property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextView *RunResultWindowTextView;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) TestBindingClass *localTestBindingClass;

 @end
```

Here are the RunResultWindow methods of interest.  Please excuse the arraycount if statement wwhich was added in there for some temporary debugging purposes and never removed.

```
 //  RunResultWindow.m methods of interest

 - (void)windowDidLoad
 {
     [super windowDidLoad];

     NSWindow *wcWindow;
     wcWindow = [self window];
     [wcWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

     NSString *teststring;
     teststring = [NSString stringWithString: @"show first time window did load "];
     [RunResultWindowTextView setString:teststring];
     [RunResultWindowTextView display];

     [localTestBindingClass addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:@"arraystatuscounter"
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
          context:NULL];

 }

 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change 
    context:(void *)context
{
  NSInteger arrayCount;
  NSString* localDisplayString;
  NSString* localNewlinePlusDisplayString;
  NSTextStorage *tempTextStorage;

  tempTextStorage = [RunResultWindowTextView textStorage];

  arrayCount = [ localTestBindingClass.StatusStrings count ];
  if (arrayCount >= 1) {
    arrayCount--;
    localDisplayString = [localTestBindingClass.StatusStrings objectAtIndex:arrayCount];
    localNewlinePlusDisplayString = [@"\n" stringByAppendingString:localDisplayString];
    [tempTextStorage beginEditing];
    [tempTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([tempTextStorage length] - 1, 0) 
                             withString:localNewlinePlusDisplayString];
    [tempTextStorage endEditing];
    [RunResultWindowTextView display];
  }

 }
```

Comment: At one point I was using the inserttext method instead of the begin Editing/endEditing sequencing and that usually froze after the first or second line which was added into the scroll view.  Again, when I put that into debug and dropped in a breakpoint into obsereValueForKeyPath method, it would work fine.  When I replaced insertText with the method shown above, it worked much better but still is not quite 100 percent ok.

Comment: An interesting question. I'm not sure what the answer is, but I think it may be a combination of detaching a new thread, updating the same observed value 6 times in the same method, and then in your observing method taking the new value directly from the observed object instead of from the `change` dictionary. This is guesswork but those are the things that don't smell right in your code. Note also that by convention, which does really come into play for KVO, you should start variable names with lower case letters. Your observed variables are fine but there are a couple that don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the KVO has much to do with it. The bit you describe as 'pretty simple' is actually really, really complicated. This is the culprit:-

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(runStatusStringSequence:) toTarget:self withObject:nil]
```

As soon as you do this you need more than a good understanding of the Cocoa frameworks - you need a good understanding of multithreaded programming and a good understanding of how the Cocoa frameworks work in a multithreaded world. It's complicated and it is hard.

You would at least need to study these

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Multithreading.pdf

If you removed the second thread altogether i still wouldn't expect this to work all the time (although it might work some of the time). You should not be calling `-display` on the text view directly. Drawing of the views, setting up drawing contexts, refresh rate, etc. is handled for you by the framework.

Just calling `-display` at a random time without knowing the status of the current drawing context would be enough to crash your app (you could easily be drawing into any random piece of memory). Add the threading into the mix and you are in more trouble.

Your method

`- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context`

is called on the background thread but the gui is not thread safe and must run on the main thread, including any interactions with gui objects like text views.

Comment: The odd thing is that the process usually works the first time I execute the program (in the debugger without breakpoints).  After shutting down the second window (and removing the KVO observer in the process) and starting it again by pressing the run button on the main window, THAT's when I start to have problems.  The other odd thing is that this ALWAYS works if I put a breakpoint into the observeValueForKeyPath method.

Comment: I guess I don't need the display method because the scroll view will refresh when the method is done.  This code was a hangover trying to refresh a scroll view multiple times within the same method in a totally different example code set.

Comment: Finally, thanks for the links and I will review them and see what I can understand out of them.  I would like to get this to running at some point because I would like to replace these simpler methods with code that does real work.

Comment: if you need to force redraw (you don't in this case) the method is -[view setNeedsDisplay:YES]. You never call -display. After reading the docs you will probably want to replace -detachNewThreadSelector: with one of the more modern methods (eg blocks, operations) apple provides to handle threading.

Comment: FYI... it was definitely due to the improper use of threads in the program.  I took it out (just had the one method invoke the other without dropping it on a second string) and it worked like a champ.  I will also replace the display logic as well.  Thanks a lot.  HUGE help.

Comment: Also took me a while to understand that the observeValueForKeyPath was being executed on the background thread and not on the main thread.  I replaced the older style thread methods with the newer GCD methods and forced the observeValueForKeyPath to be on the main thread and that took care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that actually worked.  Please excuse the mis-capitilizations and the occasional bit of odd code left over from a previous iteration of the solution.

Here is the code for the 'run' button method in the main window...

```
- (IBAction)runButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    // do a bunch of stuff

    TestBindingClass* tempTestBindingClass = [[TestBindingClass alloc] init];

    RunResultWindowController = [[RunResultWindow alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"RunResultWindow"];
    RunResultWindowController.localTestBindingClass=tempTestBindingClass;
    [RunResultWindowController showWindow:self];

    [self.outputfilestring1 becomeFirstResponder];

    [tempTestBindingClass submitStatusStringSequence];

}
```

Here is the code for the TestBindingClass as referenced above. StatusStrings is the mutable array which will contain the list of status strings which should be eventually displayed in the scroll view which is observing this class via the arraystatuscounter property.

```
 //  TestBindingClass.h

 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface TestBindingClass : NSObject {

NSMutableArray *StatusStrings;
   int arraystatuscounter;


 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *StatusStrings;
 @property  int arraystatuscounter;

 - (void) runStatusStringSequence:(id)param;
 - (void) submitStatusStringSequence;

 @end
```

This shows the implementation code of TestBindingClass. It just drops goofy little strings into the NSMutableArray one at a time and dinks the arraystatuscounter property each time it adds a string into the array to set off the KVO observation method.  The first major difference is that I used the GCD methods as suggested above...

```
//  TestBindingClass.m

 - (void) submitStatusStringSequence
 {
     NSString *parameterString;
    [self runStatusStringSequence: parameterString];
 }


 - (void) runStatusStringSequence:(id)param 
 {

dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Background Queue",NULL);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{ 

NSMutableArray *StatusStringsAlloc = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
StatusStrings = StatusStringsAlloc;

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"first string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:1];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"second string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:2];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"third string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:3];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"fourth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:4];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"fifth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:5];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"sixth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:6];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"seventh string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:7];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"last string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:8];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"first string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:1];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"second string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:2];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"third string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:3];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"fourth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:4];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"fifth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:5];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"sixth string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:6];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"seventh string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:7];

[StatusStrings addObject:[NSString stringWithString:@"last string"]];
[self setArraystatuscounter:8];

dispatch_release(backgroundQueue);

});


 }
```

Here is the RunResultWindows window controller code. The address for the TestBindingClass is added into the ivars so that it can properly set up the necessary KVO observer settings.  Also, I forced the method to run on the main thread because, I suppose, it was running on the background thread because it was invoked by a process already running on the background thread.

```
@interface RunResultWindow : NSWindowController {

    NSTextView *RunResultWindowTextView;
    TestBindingClass *localTestBindingClass;

}

- (IBAction)FinishButtonPush:(id)sender;
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context;

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSTextView *RunResultWindowTextView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TestBindingClass *localTestBindingClass;

@end
```

Here are the RunResultWindow methods of interest. Please excuse the arraycount if statement which was added in there for some temporary debugging purposes and never removed.  Note that it was forced to the main thread.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change 
        context:(void *)context
{    

    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{ 

    NSInteger arrayCount;
    NSString* localDisplayString;
    NSString* localNewlinePlusDisplayString;
    NSTextStorage *tempTextStorage;

    tempTextStorage = [RunResultWindowTextView textStorage];

    arrayCount = [ localTestBindingClass.StatusStrings count ];
    if (arrayCount >= 1) {
        arrayCount--;
        localDisplayString = [localTestBindingClass.StatusStrings objectAtIndex:arrayCount];
        localNewlinePlusDisplayString = [@"\n" stringByAppendingString:localDisplayString];
        [tempTextStorage beginEditing];
        [tempTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([tempTextStorage length] - 1, 0) 
                                 withString:localNewlinePlusDisplayString];
        [tempTextStorage endEditing];
        [RunResultWindowTextView setNeedsDisplay:YES];}

    });
}
```

Much thanks to hooleyhoop for the good pointers to the right direction.